# ios DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift

i'm pretty new with iOS and Swift but working through the DispatchQueue.main.async stuff and wondering. forgive my psuedo code:

```
func showAlert(callback) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //do some ui code to show an alert
      callback()
   } 
}
```

wont the callback be executed in the main thread as well?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main` will make the callback execute on the main thread

Comment: Yeah thats kinda what i was guessing, how would you frame that call so you get a callback, but it doesn't have to be on the main thread?  All the docs say limit what HAS to run on the main thread...

Comment: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)`